# FlexGrid dll registration during install?? Maybe?

Tags: .net, winforms, com, setup-deployment, msflexgrid

As the title suggests, I am at a loss and I'm hoping to get a little help from someone in here...

I am trying to create an installer package using VS2010 setup and deployment for a colleague's winforms app that uses a flexgrid. The project builds successfully and installs without any any errors however, when the app tries to call a flexgrid for displaying data, the error shown in the pic below is received.

[image]

I have googled until I cannot google anymore and cannot find a resolution! The dll's are being installed into the apps root directory, I have tried building the app to target both 32 and 64 bit cpu's, I have tried the corflags utility, and just about everything else I could find on the internet but nothing works.

I have never used the flexgrid in a project and I try to stay away from referencing com objects in my apps so this is definitely a first for me. The project's dependencies are shown below if this sheds any light for anyone... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should register the flexgrid during setup per call to [regsvr32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regsvr32). Without registering in the registry it can not be found and called, even, if everything is in the right place.
 Calling regsvr32 during setup prevents late asking for elevated user rights.